# a mysterous error on android ndk's syscall

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have met a very confusing problem with android ndk's syscall. It's really hard for me to make it clear in words, so please have a look at the code.

// 2nd: call the assembly function

> 1st： assembly code like

```
extern "C" int self_set_errno(int err){
    errno = err;
    return -1;
}

ENTRY(self_syscall) 
    mov     x8, x0
    mov     x0, x1
    mov     x1, x2
    mov     x2, x3
    mov     x3, x4
    mov     x4, x5
    mov     x5, x6
    svc     #0

    cmn     x0, #(MAX_ERRNO + 1)
    cneg    x0, x0, hi
    b.hi    self_set_errno

    ret
END(self_syscall)
```

> 2nd: example code to call assembly, which print the desired string-- [Fail to call write:.....]

```cpp
   int fd = STDIN_FILENO + 25;

        const char *msg = "write via syscall\n";
    int err = self_syscall(__NR_write, fd, msg, strlen(msg));
     if(err < 0){
        printf("Fail to call write: %s\n", strerror(errno));
     }else{
        printf("%s\n", "syscall write Done");
     }
```

> 3rd: make a little chang the code, now i cant get the desired string, but [syscall write Done!]

```
    int fd = STDIN_FILENO + 25;

    const char *msg = "write via syscall\n";

    if(self_syscall(__NR_write, fd, msg, strlen(msg)) < 0){
          printf("Fail to call write: %s\n", strerror(errno));
     }else{
          printf("%s\n", "syscall write Done!");
     }
```

Comment: And what is the return type of `self_syscall` in C? If it's an unsigned type then the results you describe make sense.

Comment: thanks Michael, it's really the return type makes the confusing result